# SQL SERVER 17 Default Security Groups Missing

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I've just installed SQL Server 17  on Windows 10 (with latest updates) and wish to grant permissions for SQL Server to open up .mda files from a second drive.  When attempting to grant permissions to the drive, I do not see any of the NT Services (e.g., MSSQLSERVER) to grant permission to.  In the Computer Management/Users form, they also no not show up under the UserGroups.

Was this an install error or is there another method for SQL 2017 to be granted permissions to Windows 10 folders?

Comment: Try entering "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER" (local computer location). I don't think the browse functionality works for the virtual accounts.

Comment: Marked as answered on [MS q&a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/233603/sql-server-17default-user-groups-not-created-for-w.html)